# Linq to AD Query not working

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities, active-directory, linq-to-objects

user.fld_usr_name is a string with the value random name

user is an object that is given as a parameter

```
ByVal user As GUser
```

this is the linq query that doesn't work

```
Dim result = (From usr In users Where usr.Name.Contains(user.fld_usr_name) Select usr).ToList()
```

this is the one that works

```
Dim result = (From usr In users Where usr.Name.Contains("random name") Select usr).ToList()
```

this is the error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I am using this in Linq to Active Directory library

which probably means it's linq to entities

I've tried everything

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint at the line, and see if `user.fld_usr_name` is null?

Comment: it is "random name", is it possible the whitespace character is different... (i'm starting to explore every possibility after 2 hours of frustration)

Answer (score 0):

I went up into the source code of that plugin.

LINQ just didn't work like it should with vb.net as with c#.
The plugin was C# code, but that shouldn't matter. Very strange.

I forgot the specifics since it has been a while, but it had to do something with the fact that it passes the property as a reference and not the value. Or the fact that it has to be a static... If I knew I'd fix it

I used a shared property to load all my users and worked with that. 
If someone knows how to fix this bug, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

another thought on this is that active directory has a really loose definition of what a "user" or "group" is. For instance, with groups; you have security groups and distribution groups. But AD maybe implemented as having something like security groups, authorization groups, distribution groups, location groups, etc. Then on top of that, your IT dept might have it set up so that OUs represent matrix groups and so on. But when you tell AD to bring you back a list of security groups, it'll bring you back EVERYTHING that used a security group type to create it.

Now, if you back up and look at it from the other direction, you'll find that not all "User" are actually users. Some are used differently and thus did not use "Name" property. I've run across this a few times where i had the connected drilled down into an OU that I thought was appropriate and then tried to bring back all the names in that OU. If the field isn't actually used, it'll come back as null and blow your application up. Is it poor AD design? Usually. A lot of organizations get into a habit of creating users or groups to accomplish tasks rather than doing it in a way that physically represents the organization. For instance, creating a user account that is used by a web application only, or creating new groups just to encompass a few permissions for a few special people like I described earlier. And the problem with this of course, is that you try to look at it from a database perspective when coding your application. But it's not a database; it's simply a collection of collections. An unstandardized, dynamic, flat file. :(

So as it possibly applies to you, your linq query maybe returning zilch because the Name field is in fact null for that collection. It is for this reason, that I now only use GUIDs or Native GUIDs. In cases where you only have a name, then use the searcher and grab guids, then use those guids to create a directory entry that WILL have the info you're looking for.